# Setting CPPFLAGS through command line

Tags: c++, makefile

Suppose in my makefile I have

```
   program_INCLUDE_DIRS += ../inc 
   CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
```

Now I want to include a directory named ../inc2 (which is present one directory above where I am running the makefile) while running the makefile through the command line

I know that I should set the ../inc2 directory to CPPFLAGS.

Please suggest me the syntax of the command to include the directory ../inc2 through command line. Also I dont want to override the existing directory included in the makefile(../inc above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` means `CPPFLAGS` is appended instead of replaced.  That means you can set it in your shell and the existing directories will get appended, like this:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I../inc2
make
```

If you need to do this a lot, the better solution would be to change your makefile to say:

```
program_INCLUDE_DIRS += ../inc ../inc2
```

Comment: @Karl....I am not able to acheive this using export feature...can you suggest way of doing this directly through command line like......make CPPFLAGS+=-I../inc2. Also, I guess on export the ../inc2 is being over ridden with ../inc2

Comment: What shell are you using?  `CPPFLAGS=-I../inc2 make` also works in most unix-like shells.  I don't know what it would be for windows.